# Why the Path disappear when I input Time in Tableau

Tags: path, tableau-api, analysis

I am trying to visualize a path from one location to another ordered by time. According to Tableau, after inputting locations and changing the mark type to the path mark, just drag the date to the path and exact the date, the path will connect the location in the order of date. However, my data works before I drag the date. Every time I drag the date to path, the path disappears.

https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-gb/maps_howto_flow.htm

I've followed this link and format my data that way. but at the last step, the path disappears when drag date to the path.

[image]

Path disappear when input time

Answer (score 0):

I have sloved the problem with arranging a time. Also should put time on details, not on the path.